# What type of security has been used with WCF on Azure that would be compatible with Silverlight?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, security, ssl, azure

Has anybody gotten any type of security to work with WCF on Azure that would be compatible with Silverlight?

I have already tried transport security on basic http binding, but it [does not work](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazure/thread/f3778772-e74e-4b5e-9ae5-72ecc0138ff1).

Comment: There you go! Now stand back, leave it alone for a bit, ok?

Comment: Was going to comment "Yessir" but a comment bust be at laest 10 characters...seriously...too many limitations on a site that prides itself on ease of use.

Comment: @divitae: The site works fine. For someone looking for help, you shouldn't be so quick to mock the site.

Comment: Really, I'm not mocking it.  I actually really love the site.  I'm quite addicted to the site already.  Which makes its arbitrary limitations when I find them even more frustrating.

Comment: @divitae: The restrictions all have good reasons. If you are so curious, I suggest you read the FAQ, UV, blog and CodingHorror. You might learn a thing or two.

Comment: @divitiae: You're addicted already???!!! NOooooOOOoOoOOO, save your self, you're still on time... this is a traaaaaaaaa.... Here +1 to feed your addiction.

Comment: @oscar :) thanks...yeah I'm being converted to the "stacker" religion.  I love the site and its versitility.  I mean, all I have to do type in humor and get the top programming jokes!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at these WCF Azure samples: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfazure

Answer (score -1):

Have a look here: http://silverlightuk.blogspot.com/2008/03/silverlight-wcf-and-aspnet.html

Looks to me like basic Forms based authentication should work for you.

Edit: In your comment you say you prefer not to use forms based authentication.

Have you tried the advice supplied here: http://blogs.msdn.com/mikeormond/archive/2007/07/12/accessing-asp-net-application-services-from-silverlight-part-2.aspx

Comment: I would rather not use forms based authentication because there is no mechanism to log somebody in through silverlight without using another service, which I can't use securely without another way of securing other than forms.

Comment: Some of the reason why my last question that was so critized was longer is that I tried to explain all that.  Now, you have answered this question, and you've been quite helpful regarding SO stuff, so poof, its answered.  I'll wait for MSDN.

Comment: @divitae: You are far too impatient. You need to work to get to the right answer.

Comment: @richb thank you for your continued help, I'm sorry that I am seeming impatient.  I think I have a bigger problem though in that I really need to get transport security working to secure the data that will be transmitted as well.  These other solutions would just be gerat things to have on top o ssl

Comment: @Divitae: Which is why you should not accept my answer. Be patient, this is the slow time of the day. Tomorrow you will likely get more answers from people much more knowledgeable than me, but not if they think I answered your question.